# Apply a list of character expressions stored in a data.table column to the other columns per row

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with variables as columns and one column storing a different function for each row as character. I would like to simply apply each function to its row and store output in a new column without using a for loop as I need it to be fast and have 25000 rows.

If I take a simplified example, let's say I have a data.table dt:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9),d=c("a+b+c","a*b*c","c/a*b"))
dt
   a b c     d
1: 1 4 7 a+b+c
2: 2 5 8 a*b*c
3: 3 6 9 c/a*b
```

I would like to have this as a result:

```
   a b c     d   e
1: 1 4 7 a+b+c  12
2: 2 5 8 a*b*c  80
3: 3 6 9 c/a*b  18
```

So far the only solution I have found is a for loop, but it's slow for my 25000 rows and 32 variables:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
    dt[i,e:=eval(parse(text=dt[i,d]))]
}
```

I have been searching for quite a while (tried with eval, sapply,...) but so far with no success, I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What do you gain with the initialization: `dt$e <- numeric(nrow(dt))` before the loop? What I have in mind, `eval(parse(...))` is slow. How many "rules" do you have in col `d`? (Can you use integers only?)

Comment: `dt[, e:=dt[, eval(parse(text=d)), by=1:nrow(dt)]$V1]` works but you want to avoid using `eval(parse(...))` ...

Comment: When you are doing `by = 1:nrow(dt)` in R - you are doing it wrong/picked wrong language

Comment: @DavidArenburg I thought it was when you're doing `apply(df, 1, ...)` ;-p

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I followed @DavidArenburg 's suggestion and changed the way I was storing the functions. Much longer to code, but now it takes 5 seconds and not 5 minutes...

Comment: @OliviaB If you can show what you found in an answer (preferably using the example data here), it might benefit others.

Answer (score 2):

```
interpret <- function(expr, .SD) eval(parse(text = expr[1]), envir = .SD)
dt[, e := interpret(d,.SD), by = d, .SDcols = c("a", "b", "c")]
dt
```

returns:

```
> dt
   a b c     d   e
1: 1 4 7 a+b+c  12
2: 2 5 8 a*b*c  80
3: 3 6 9 c/a*b  18
```

A dummy bench :

```
l <- lapply(1:1e5, function(i) dt)
bigdt <- rbindlist(l)
bigdt[, e:=interpret(d,.SD), by=d, .SDcols=c("a", "b", "c")]
bigdt
microbenchmark(for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  bigdt[i,e:=eval(parse(text=bigdt[i,d]))]
}, bigdt[, e:=interpret(d,.SD), by=d, .SDcols=c("a", "b", "c")])
```

gave me

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                             expr
 for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {     bigdt[i, `:=`(e, eval(parse(text = bigdt[i, d])))] }
     bigdt[, `:=`(e, interpret(d, .SD)), by = d, .SDcols = c("a",      "b", "c")]
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
 2.693427 2.833544 3.240561 3.043713 3.150880  6.212202   100   a 
 6.891739 7.280915 9.988198 8.496646 8.721075 69.666926   100   b
>
```

Answer (score 0):

`invoke_map()` from package `purrr` is designed to iterate over a list of functions and a list of parameters to each function.

Here is an alternative, slightly long winded, idea how to solve this problem.

```
dt <- data.frame(a=rep(c(1,2,3, 5), 10),b= rep(c(4,5,6, 5),10),c=rep(c(7,8,9, 5), 10),d=rep(c("a+b+c","a*b*c","c/a*b", "a+b+c"), 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create functions in the environment based on column d

```
funs_map <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(unique(dt$d))){
eval(parse(text = paste('f', i, '<- function(', 'a, b, c', ') { return(' , unique(dt$d)[i] , ')}', sep=''))) 
  funs_map[i,1] <- unique(dt$d)[i]
  funs_map[i,2] <- paste('f', i, sep="")
  }
```

Create a list of functions to iterate over - this will be the .f argument to invoke_map

```
funs_list <- as.list(funs_map$V2[match(dt$d , funs_map$V1)])
```

Last column will not be necessary anymore

```
dt <- dt[-4]
```

Create a list of parameters for each function - this appears to be the most time consuming step

```
params <-vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(dt))
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){
params[[i]] <-   as.list(dt[i,])
}
```

Iterate over functions

```
result <- invoke_map(funs_list, params)
```

Putting this code into a function and benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark(apply_funs(dt))
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 apply_funs(dt) 19.27345 20.34213 21.09592 20.66714 21.63639 26.83376   100
```

Original code:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                       expr      min
 for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {     dt[i, `:=`(e, eval(parse(text = dt[i, d])))] } 353.7435
       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 358.0244 362.6764 360.3644 362.9175 439.9213   100
```

And tokiloutok solution (fastest):

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                      expr      min
 dt[, `:=`(e, interpret(d, .SD)), by = d, .SDcols = c("a", "b",      "c")] 0.780877
        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
 0.8148745 0.8432403 0.822787 0.8480175 1.203817   100
```